# I'm installing opencv in ubuntu 16.04. After installing the necessary prerequisites I used the following command:-

Tags: command-line, software-installation, cmake, opencv

```
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~$ cd ~/opencv
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~/opencv$ cd build
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~/opencv/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

During the installation of OpenCV it produced an error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/avi/opencv" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

After `ls /home/avi/opencv`:

```
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~$ cd ~/opencv
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~/opencv$ ls
build  opencv  opencv_contrib
```

after the `ls /home/avi/opencv/opencv`:

```
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~/opencv$ cd opencv
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~/opencv/opencv$ ls
3rdparty  cmake           CONTRIBUTING.md  doc      LICENSE  platforms  samples
apps      CMakeLists.txt  data             include  modules  README.md
avi@avi-VPCEB46FG:~/opencv/opencv$
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657)

Answer (score 0):

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is present in the folder `/home/avi/opencv/opencv`. So to build in `/home/avi/opencv/build` (alias `~/opencv/build`), you should use:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../opencv
```